# Whether I can download the data of `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home`?

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive

I can not mount the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home` to `/home` directory.
but now whether I can download the data of `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home`?

I can not mount a `lv` partition to a directory, whether I can download the data of the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home`?

**edit01**

i can not fsck to repair the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home`, so i can not mount.

---

**EDIT-02**

This bellow is my tried:

```
[root@localhost VolGroup]# mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /home/
Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home,
       Missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       Dmesg | tail or so

[root@localhost VolGroup]# fsck -t ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
Fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
E2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Read block 114327552 (invalid parameter) Error ignore error <y>?

Mandatory coverage <y>? Yes

Write block 114327552 (invalid parameter) error. Ignore error <y>?

The superblock contains an invalid ext3 log (inode 8).
Clear <y>? Yes

*** ext3 journal has been deleted - filesystem is now ext2 only ***

Superblock has_log flag is clear, but a log inode is present.
Clear <y>? Yes

The file system size (according to the super block) is 228899840 block s
The physical size of the device is 26214400 block s
Either the super block or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Interrupt <y>? Yes

Write block 114327552 (invalid parameter) error. Ignore error <y>?

[root@localhost VolGroup]# mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /home/
Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home,
       Missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       Dmesg | tail or so
```

Comment: This looks pretty well trashed. Restore from backup or contact a data recovery firm.